# Why can't i filter a Deep nested query in graphql?

Tags: graphql, hasura

So i just started using graphql recently (last week to be precise). I get the concept of being able to filter queries with the 'where' argument and all but i noticed when i try to get objects from a deep nested query it becomes somewhat impossible. So say i have 'domestic_worker_nextofkin' query that should get fullname, mobile_phone1, and relationship where 'archived' _is_null equals true as given below:

```
domestic_workers_nextofkin(where: {archived:{_is_null: true}}){
    full_name
    mobile_phone1
    domestic_workers_relationships{
      relationship
    }
  }
}
```

The query above does it's intended job and gets the full_name, mobile_phone1 and relationship.

But my current problem is that when this query is deeply nested as shown below (the asterisked code):

```
query User($userId: Int) {
     domestic_workers_news{
          title
          date_created
          summary
          url
        }
    users_user(where: {id: {_eq: $userId}}) {
      domestic_workers_pictures(order_by: {id: desc}, limit: 1) {
        id
      }
      id
      password
      username
      first_name
      last_name
      email
      gender
      birth_date
      mobile_phone1
      mobile_phone2
      home_address_street
      home_address_town
      home_address_lga
      home_address_state
      home_address_country
      home_address_postal_code
      job_title
      workplace
      verified
      agreed_terms
      date_joined
      last_modified
      domestic_workers_workers {
        domestic_workers_pictures(order_by: {id: desc}, limit: 1) {
          id
        }
        id
        first_name
        last_name
        other_name
        email
        mobile_phone1
        mobile_phone2
        home_town
        home_state
        service
        birth_date
        gender
        date_created
        current_employer_id
        domestic_workers_relationships{
          id
          payment
          payment_currency
          start_date
          relationship
          domestic_workers_agent {
            full_name
            mobile_phone1
            domestic_workers_relationships{
              relationship
            }
            domestic_workers_pictures(order_by: {id: desc}, limit: 1) {
              id
            }
          }


**domestic_workers_nextofkin (where: {archived:{_is_null: true}}) {
        full_name
        mobile_phone1
         domestic_workers_relationships{
          relationship
        }
      }
    }**
        domestic_workers_reviews {
          id
          score
          summary
          date_created
          users_user {
            first_name
            last_name
            domestic_workers_pictures(order_by: {id: desc}, limit: 1) {
              id
            }
          }
        }
        employerRelationships: domestic_workers_relationships(order_by: {id: desc}, limit: 1, where: {relationship: {_eq: "Employer"}}) {
         end_date
         relationship
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

It shows the 'where' argument highlighted as red, which possibly means that the 'where' argument shouldnt be placed there which seems rather confusing to me. Can anyone explain why this happens and show me a workaround to pull off the task i'm trying to perform? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#filter-nested-objects):

> The where argument can be used in **array relationships** as well to filter the nested objects. **Object relationships** have only one nested object and hence they do not expose the where argument.

`users_user` is an **object relationship** (it returns a single object instead of an array of them), so it cannot be filtered.

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining that. But from your knowledge of graphql what would you advice me to do concerning this issue?

Comment: Ok, I just read the docs and I get what you were implying. But for my case, its actually the domestic_worker_nextofkin that returns a single object. Thanks a lot.